# User with linked account rep bonus doesn't go below 101 after downvotes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, linked-accounts

[This user](https://serverfault.com/users/114148/duli-chan) opened a linked account on SF and asked a question which was promptly voted to -6. He should have 89 rep from what I can tell, but currently has 101.

I assume that this is a bug. Thoughts?

Comment: This just happened to me and I was going to ask the same question. I went down to 99 then bumped back up to 101.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No bug. Check out the user's [rep history](https://serverfault.com/users/114148/duli-chan?tab=reputation). Here's the timeline:

```
Time  | Activity                   | Rep change | Total rep
------+----------------------------+------------+--------------------------------
0755Z | Account created            | N/A        | 1
1255Z | Question asked             | N/A        | 1
1325Z | Votes accrue: 0 up, 6 down | -12        | 1: can't go below 1 on SE sites
2028Z | Association bonus awarded  | +100       | 101
```

Comment: Hm. So, I understand *why* it's like that now, but is that *how* it should work? It seems wrong to me.

Comment: Remove your downvote and re-cast it? Lol If you're really dead-set on him losing his 2 rep.

Comment: Then you probably also don't like how you can downvote a 1-rep user, immediately undo it and see the user's rep balloon to 3, @MDMarra.

Comment: @PopularDemand You're right, though I do use that to give a new user that asks a good question +7

Comment: Even with the new rep changes this still happens?  Man, that's lame.  The order you do things should not affect your rep.

Comment: @Popular - That's no longer possible in 99% of cases.

Comment: If you've got enough rep to get a linked account bonus, you're not exactly starting out.

Comment: Thanks @NickCraver, good to know.